# Is there a common interface for android apps and web applets?

Tags: java, android, applet

I'm looking (for part of a Computer Science project) to create a suite of apps that demonstrate and explain a certain set of topics. I'd like them to run on Android and be available through a browser.

They'll have input (buttons, sliders, text boxes, etc), and will need to draw diagrams.

At what level can I reuse my code? (eg, is there a way to contain my applet inside an android view? Could I use the input methods from the applet? Will there be a performance hit due to not using native controls?)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's any commonality between the two. Your best bet is to create interfaces for all the bits that differ between the two platforms, write your suite of apps using these interfaces and then create implementations for the interfaces for each platform.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by web applet? If you mean a webpage, you can look into trigger.io which will allow you to write apps in html for android, iphone and a webbrowser all within the same codebase.

Comment: I'm having issues with getting java applets to play atm, but I think this is the type of thing I was going for:
http://www.nbb.cornell.edu/neurobio/land/OldStudentProjects/cs490-96to97/anson/BezierPatchApplet/

Comment: I don't think there is a common platform for java appets and android apps.